# Clean up dates out of MongoDB for display on front end

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have some dates that I import and they save as Dates in Mongo, when I take them out Mongo appends time UTC blah blah.

When I retrieve the dates out of Node how can I clean them up so they look good.

Current output: 
    Thu Jan 20 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)

if I can just remove everything after 2011 that would be fine...

Comment: I would HIGHLY recommend taking a look at http://momentjs.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

via **Date()**
You can specify a particular date by passing to the Date() method a datetime string. For example:

```
new Date("<YYYY-mm-dd>") which returns the ISODate with the specified date.
new Date("<YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:ss>") which specifies the datetime in local datetime and returns the ISODate with the specified datetime in UTC.
new Date("<YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:ssZ>") which specifies the datetime in UTC and returns the ISODate with the specified datetime in UTC.
```

via **$dateToString**

Consider this document

```
{
  "_id" : 1,
  "item" : "abc",
  "price" : 10,
  "quantity" : 2,
  "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T08:15:39.736Z")
}
```

we can format it like this

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $project: {
          yearMonthDay: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } },
          time: { $dateToString: { format: "%H:%M:%S:%L", date: "$date" } }
       }
     }
   ]
)
```

You can find more details [Date](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/Date/) and [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)

Answer (score 0):

```
`db.collection.aggregate([
      {
       $project: {
         formatedDate: { $dateToString:
                  { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$inputdate"} 
                       }
                   } 
      } 
])
```

`

$inputdate is your ISO date